# url_strategy stops caching using Workbox Service Worker

Tags: flutter, path, service-worker, workbox, flutter-plugin

I am developing a PWA using Flutter. To cache assets, I am using [Workbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/).

When I use the [url_strategy](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy/versions) package, it cleans the hash (#) from the urls. e.g. ( `http://localhost:400/homepage` ).

But the assets are cached for the hash path ( `http://localhost:400/#/homepage` ) and won't work on paths that do not start with the #.

I want the caching to work for urls without the hash ( `http://localhost:400/homepage` ). I have spent hours on this and cannot find the this is happening.

Solution I found is to not use the setPathUrlStrategy() but I want URLs without hashes.

JS code in my `flutter/web/index.html` file registers a custom service worker that caches assets according to the hash urls ( `http://localhost:400/#/homepage` ) in Flutter.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerUrl: './service_worker.js', # Giving custom service worker file
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

service_worker.js

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.2.0/workbox-sw.js');

const { precacheAndRoute } = workbox.precaching;

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

workbox-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: 'build/web/',
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{json,otf,ttf,js,wasm,png,html}'],
  swSrc: 'service_worker.js',
  swDest: 'build/web/service_worker.js',
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 10000000,
};
```

main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  // Here we set the URL strategy for our web app.
  // It is safe to call this function when running on mobile or desktop as well.
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```